# Как хранить аудиофайлы и их метаданные (имена), чтобы их можно было легко локализовать?

Tags: android, android-assets

Мне нужно хранить аудиофайлы и их метаданные (имена). Была идея просто взять название из имени файла, но столкнулся с проблемой локализации.

Можно было бы установить строковый ресурс, указывающий, в зависимости от локали, на разные подкаталоги в активах, но для этого нужно было бы сохранять копии аудиофайлов для каждого языка, так что это не вариант.

Другой способ — создать подпапки в папке с ресурсами для каждой локали, где находятся текстовые файлы, содержащие локализованные метаданные и ссылки на аудиоресурсы.

Помогите найти лучший вариант.

Comment: аудио можно хранить в папке Raw. и ее можно локализовать как и другие ресурсы.

Comment: @Wlad там нет возможности структурировать, создавать подпапки. Так же разве мне не придется делать копии аудио для разных языков?

Comment: я соглашусь с @Wlad, а вот по поводу копий - придется конечно, как же вы содержимое файла будете отлавливать?) по логике вам можно просто сделать в названии файла код языка типа _en, _de и дальше при запросе файлов из папки ресурсов добавлять туда нужную вам локаль и все